# Keyboard, Video, Mouse Switch Problems

Tags: kvm-switch

I've installed Mythbuntu 16.04 64 Bit Primary Backend on a Dell Optiplex 745 Desktop and I'm in the process of setting up another Backend on another Dell Optiplex 745 SFF desktop. I've installed a KVM switch to allow me to work on both systems using the same monitor, keyboard and mouse, and this is where I'm running into problems - I can switch from system #1 to system #2 just fine, but when I switch back the monitor looks like the system has shut down the SVGA output, and I can switch back the the other system with the same results!

I can only power the systems down to get them back. Is there some way to keep the video alive? This doesn't happen when I use the switch on my Windows servers.

Comment: Rather than using a kvm switch with all of the cables, try Synergy. It may work in your application. See http://symless.com/synergy/ for more info. If you have the getdeb repository, you'll also find Synergy in Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be on the design of the KVM switch (I don't know what model and maker of the switch).  Looks like the KVM switch does not have built-in EDID emulation (feeding the EDID information to all connected systems, no matter if the systems are targeted/selected or not).

I suggest that you should either find a KVM switch support "Full-time EDID emulation" or adding external EDID emulator to existing KVM switch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question and it's happening to me and others as well.
My KVM is really good and fully supports EDID, but my monitor screen (a SHARP over HDMI) goes from normal to green every time I switch back.  I have figured out a somewhat lame fix below.

Your KVM has to emulate the monitor when it is disconnected to maintain a stable desktop layout. I have connected 5 different systems to mine (including this same linux computer but running Mac OS X); as with the poster of the question, all those systems switch back reliably maintaining the correct layout and color scheme. This is not purely a hardware issue; of course the KVM triggers it.

Although I have extensively used XRANDR before switching screen to a different computer, while switching screen to a different computer, and after switching back to linux and observing the errant color change. I have captured the output including the dumping of the EDID data. It is always identical. The computer is definitely seeing the same EDID data from the KVM with the monitor not really connected.

Fix:
When I run xrandr once while the kvm is switched away, the monitor will display correctly when I return. Conversely if I wait to run xrandr until I am switched back, running xrandr has no effect. Running more than once has no effect either so it can't be automated. And sometimes it fails and I still need to disconnect and reconnect the cable.

Ideally some sort of trigger scheme would be useful I have [seen some creative solutions](https://github.com/fberrez/display-daemon) for noticing when a monitor is disconnected and running xrandr scripts, but that won't happen here. The KVM is doing its job for the most part and the computer will not see a disconnect.